# How to regex in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I want to add some text before each `return`
For example we have :

```
void* foo (){
   if (something){ 
   return A;
   }
do_something;
// That return word may be ignored, because it's comment
do_something;
returns(); //It may ignored to
return ;
}
```

I need :

```
void* foo (){
   if (something){
   END;
   return A;
   }
do_something;
// That return word may be ignored, becouse it's comment
do_something;
returns(); //It may ignored to
END;
return ;
}
```

I can't build regex for search request. It may looks like
"

> **return**"< *some text here started with space symbol, or nothing* >**;**<*endline*>

How I can make it in VIM?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't build regex for search request." What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: You can substitute patterns in vim by first getting to the command mode.  That is done by typing ':'.  Then you can substitute patterns in the whole file by '%s///'.   If you had a file with the text 'test' then '%s/test/two\rlines/' will replace the word 'test' with 'two', then a newline, then 'line'.   For you '%s/returns\(\);/returns\(\);\rEND;/' may be what you are going for, but I'm not 100% on what you are intending.

Comment: A tutorial on and reference for Vim regular expressions: http://vimregex.com/

Comment: Thanks for tutorial. I don't understand how can i missed it when googled.
About search requests.....
Before it I made macroses with simple logic: `/return^MOEND;^[<80>kd` (search "return" and add "END;" before it), and run it 1000 times (with `set nowrapscan`). Main problem was that `/return` search word "return" in coments. 
The main question was "What regex (for  "return ;" "return var;" but not "// return") i need write after `/` to search what i whant? "

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using hold registers is an easy way to do this:

```
%s/^\(\s*\)\(return\>.*\)/\1END;\r\1\2/g
```

The meanings:

```
%s - global substitute
/  - field separator
^  - start of line
\( - start hold pattern
\s - match whitespace
*  - 0 or more times
\) - end hold pattern
\> - end of word boundary (prevent returns matching return)
.  - match any character
\1 - recall hold pattern number 1
\2 - recall hold pattern number 2
\r - <CR>
g  - Replace all occurrences in the line
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `global` command as follows:

```
:g/^\s*return\>/normal OEND;
```

It searches for lines having any number of whitespace and the word return, executes the command `O` and adds the "END;"

Bonus feature the END; is 'auto indented'.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know about multiple repeats. I take macros, set `nowrap scan` and repeat macros about 1000 times before that day. But now i'll do same work easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a substitution:

```
:%s/\(return\)/END;\r\1/g
```

The substitution searches for occurrences of `return`, remembers such occurrences and places `END;` followed by a newline in front of those occurrences. You may want to read up on regular expressions in vim's substitution. Note that `\(\)` groups characters such that a group can be referenced in the substitution again.

**Edit**

Lets make that example more specific (I hope I hit your corner cases):

```
:%s/\(return\(\((\|\s\)[^;]\)*;\)/END\r\1/g
```

The regular expression matches every occurrence of `return` which is followed by whitespace or opening parenthesis and subsequent characters until `;` is encountered. Such an occurrence is substituted with itself and a prepended `END`.

Comment: I think it's a little more complicated than that. The poster has some cases in the code that he wants ignored and your regex will hit all of them. `return` appears multiple times like in `returns();` and in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

`:%s/.*\(\/\/.*\)\@<!\<return\>.*/END\r&/g`

This basically says "find any line with a `return` statement that's not in a comment and replace it with END, newline, then the original line". The key to this is the lookbehind (`\(\/\/.*\)\@<!`) which essentially ignores any instances of `return` in a comment. The `\<return\>` makes sure you only search for `return` and not something like `returns`.

I tested using:

```
//return here
return; // return as mentioned
if (cornerCase) { return 1; }
returns();
return 0;
```

Which became this after the replace:

```
//return here
END
return; // return as mentioned
END
if (cornerCase) { return 1; }
returns();
END
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/^\(\s*\)\<return\>/\1END;\r&/
```

Use `&` to return what was matched. Similar to `\0` in Perl.